# How to chain actions in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, symfony, redux, react-redux, api-platform.com

How to chain actions to **get the url** of **image property** when I fetch the post list.

I've made a request that fetch all posts, and it gives me a link for the property "image".

***mywebsite/api/recipes?_page=1*** :

```
{
    "@context": "/api/contexts/Recipes",
    "@id": "/api/recipes",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "@id": "/api/recipes/524",
            "@type": "Recipes",
            "id": 524,
            "category": "/api/categories/11",
            "title": "NewPost",
            "content": "This is a new post",
            "time": "50 minutes",
            "image": [
                "/api/images/37"
            ],
            "slug": "new-post",
            "createdAt": "2020-06-30T10:26:00+00:00",
            "comments": [
                "/api/comments/1359",
                "/api/comments/1360"
            ]
        },
        ........
```

and the result for ***mywebsite/api/images/37*** is :

```
{
    "url": "/images/5efbe9a4a1404818118677.jpg"
}
```

now in my ***actions*** i have

```
export const recipesListError = (error) => ({
   type: RECIPES_LIST_ERROR,
   error
});

export const recipesListReceived = (data) => ({
   type: RECIPES_LIST_RECEIVED,
   data
});

export const recipesListFetch = (page = 1) => {
   return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(recipesListRequest());
      return requests.get(`/recipes?_page=${page}`)
         .then(response => dispatch(recipesListReceived(response)))
         .catch(error => dispatch(recipesListError(error)));
   }
};
```

so the **first request** is recipesListFetch, now what is missing is the **second request** to get the image and then return the url so i can directly have access to the image for each post

the easy solution would have been to use normalization_context groups has
i'm working with symfony api platform but it still gives me a link for the image property, I think because it's a ManyToMany relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There don't seem to have the need for normalisation. The images and comments are specific to the recipe.

Make the then block callback as async fun and inside then block loop thru the `recipes` array first and then loop thru the `image` array and make api call for the image and await for it.

```js
export const recipesListFetch = (page = 1) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(recipesListRequest());
    return requests
      .get(`/recipes?_page=${page}`)
      .then(async (response) => {
        //make then callback as async fun
        const recipes = response["hydra:member"];
        const imagesForTheRecipie = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {//loop thru recipies
          for (let j = 0; j < recipes[i].image.length; j++) {//loop thru images for each recipie
            const imageUrl = recipes[i].image[j];//grab the image url
            const image = await requests.get(`/${imageUrl}}`);
            imagesForTheRecipie.push(image);
          }
          recipes[i].image = imagesForTheRecipie; //mutate the object which will directly update the response
        }
        dispatch(recipesListReceived(response));
      })
      .catch((error) => dispatch(recipesListError(error)));
  };
};
```

**Note** - If you want to `normalise` then you can choose to nomalise data for the `categories` as the same category will be used by many recipes. In that case you will have to re-structure your reducers.

Comment: thanks ! i can see both post list and the images in my browser... but how do i make the relation between the post and the images related to when i render my page ?

Comment: you will kind of need to use a combination of `selectors` and `reselect` .... mixing up multiple topics in 1 question may not fully help others ... so could you please open a new qn sharing your code of your reducer and the component ... if your current qn (chaining actions) is solved, then you can close this qn ..

Comment: no problem ! if you want to check it out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769213/associate-images-with-post-in-reactjs